# While loop with asynchronous problems

Tags: javascript, mysql, while-loop, async-await

I'm trying to implement a Signup back-end process where the user id is created randomly. The process checks if the user email exists. If not, it creates a random 24 character id. After this, it checks if this id already exists in other user. If not it should create the user in the database (mysql).

The functions for creating the id and to query for it in the database are:

```
const makeId = (length) => {
  var result = '';
  var characters =
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
};

getUserByID = (id, callback) => {
  db.query(`SELECT userID FROM users WHERE userID=?`, [id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err, null);
    },
    return callback(null, results);
  });
};
```

So I called the functions this way:

```
let found = true;
while (found === true) {
   let userID = makeId(24);
   getUserByID(userID, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
         return res.status(500).json({ errors: 'Database connection error' });
      }
      if (!result.length) {
         found = false;
      }
   });
}
```

For some reason that I am not understanding, this way is giving an infinite loop. I tried to log each of the steps, even inside the getUserByID and I think it doesn't complete this function. I suppose it's because the query is not waiting for the id (or vice-versa). I also tried a try catch method, .then().catch(){} method, async await in the functions and the async outside the while loop, but for some reason they didn't work. Any ideas of what can be wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: are you able to get into the second `if` statement, where `found` is set to false? If so, you can use `break` to stop the `while` loop

Comment: Asynchronous callbacks like the one you're passing to `getUserByID` are only fired once the main script's synchronous code has run and executed. Your `while` is synchronous and runs first, and only once your while loop has finished and your main script is complete will your callback be executed. However, your while loop can never terminate as the only thing that can stop it from running is within the callback, which will only run once the while loop has finished executing (which never happens). Maybe consider using some sort of uuid package instead of sending multiple queries?

Comment: Probably is the best solution. Nevertheless, I would like to understand if there is a solution for my case. Just a matter of problem comprehension. Thanks